# How to generate an OpenGL texture from non-continous data?

Tags: c++, opengl, opencv

My goal is to create a texture from a webcam image. I get the image via OpenCV's new *VideoCapture* interface from a *Logitech QuickCam for Notebooks* webcam. The problem is that I get *non-continuos* data this way, which means that each row of the matrix holding my image data has a gap at the end.

The layout of my image data is as following:

```
width = frame.cols * frame.elemSize(); // 640 * 3 = 1920 byte
step = frame.step[0]; // 2560 byte
gap = step - width; // 640 byte
```

However, I did not find a way to tell OpenGL to skip the last 640 byte of every row when loading the texture. I wonder if there is a way doing that? If I just load the data as texture anyway, the image does not show correct (no surprise here). See http://picasaweb.google.com/103165673068768416583/Opencv#5562843683120979026

The best solution would be to get continuos data in the first place, but again I could not find out how to do this (with OpenCV). If I copy the data to a continuos matrix, it is displayed correctly (see http://picasaweb.google.com/103165673068768416583/Opencv#5562843692435711522).

However, I don't want to copy data if I dont have to. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a combination of `GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT` and `GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH`.

In your specific case, this would give :

```
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 4)         // as 2560 is a multiple of 4
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH, 2560/3)   // to consider each row having this number of pixels
```

But all in all, are you sure that each pixel have 3 bytes ?

I've noticed that your `step` is `frame.cols * 4`, I would not be surprised if each pixel had a padding byte to have an alignment that is a multiple of 4.

Have you tried instructing OpenGL that your source data is GL_RGBA or GL_BGRA, while leaving the texture internal format to GL_RGB ?

Comment: Wow, this actually works! Thanks, man! I also tried BGRA as source format but the output is still wrong (see http://picasaweb.google.com/103165673068768416583/Opencv#5562907830518954274), which I expected because frame.elemSize() = 3.

Comment: Glad I could help, weird image format though. Don't forget to reset ROW_LENGTH to 0 after your texture upload or you'll end up being bitten by this :P